# Enabling systemd service with preseed

Tags: linux, debian, preseed

I'm trying to enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service to output getty to serial console as well as tty0.

I have tried running `systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0` but I suspect that systemd might not be running when late_command is running.

Then I tried making the symlink manually with `ln -s /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/serial-getty@ttyS0.service` and after the install getty.target.wants only contains getty@tty1.service.

I can't use `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8` kernel parameter because then messages from the init system and the system logger will only appear on the first serial port and I want them to appear on tty0.

I'm using `in-target` with late_command.

Example:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target \
    ln -s /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service \
    /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/serial-getty@ttyS0.se‌​rvice
```

Does anyone have any experience or any idea on how to enable services in preseed config?

Comment: `systemctl enable` does not require systemd to be running.  You can verify if the command worked (or not) just by looking for the symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/`.  If it's there and things are not working, your problem is something else.

Comment: There's only getty@tty1.service in `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/`after `d-i preseed/late_command string in-target systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0`

Comment: Looks like cloud-init is disabling serial-getty@ttyS0 for some reason. If I don't install cloud-init it seems to work.